# Should the JWT from Firebase be the same as running "gcloud auth print-identity-token"?

Tags: firebase, request, jwt, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run app that is not open to public traffic. It requires authorized traffic.

I obtain the JWT from a Firebase sign-in flow. I obtain the JWT after signing in using an account and then running `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()` to get a JWT.

With that same account, running `gcloud auth print-identity-token` on my machine, I get a different JWT than above.

I use a get request with the Authorization header to my Cloud Run application. This account mentioned (which is the same in either case) has an Owner role within IAM for this project. Therefore, there should be sufficient privileges.

In the cases I have described above, the first example returns a forbidden 401 Unauthorized response from my Cloud Run application. The second example, works correctly and returns a response.

Why do I get different JWT for the same account? Why does one of these methods work and the other doesn't--they are the same accounts?

Comment: 1) Either the tokens represent different identities or the **aud** (audience) is different/wrong, the **iss** (issuer) is different or the identity is not authorized. 2) Decode the JWTs. Compare the keys in the payload. Since you have not included details on the identity that was used to create the OIDC Identity Token, the token's audience, or the OIDC tokens we can only guess. 3) There are two types of Firebase tokens. One is not compatible because the Issuer is different.

Comment: 4) This link details the Header/Payload/Signature: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#token_format and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens